# Copy and Paste Range VBA PowerPoint in EXCEL 2010

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

This is the code that I am currently using. I want to copy and paste a range to a specific powerpoint. I can do this fine using the following code but the quality is not very good and I was hoping there is another way around this.

```
Sub This ()
Dim PPApp  As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

        ' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pptPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Desktop\Template.pptx")


Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
' Reference active presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
Sheets("Test").Select
Range("B6:Q46").CopyPicture
' Paste the range
With PPPres.Slides(18).Shapes.PasteSpecial
                .Top = 86.8969
                .Left = 19.98417
                .Height = 150.7964
                .Width = 600.5262
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried this:

```
Sheets("Test").Select
Range("B6:Q46").Copy
' Paste the range
With PPPres.Slides(18).PasteSpecial
                .Top = 86.8969
                .Left = 19.98417
                .Height = 150.7964
                .Width = 600.5262
End With
```

But this does not work, and I was wondering if there is a way to do this. When I copy and paste I want to keep the formatting as well.

**Addition**

I have done some research online and I have seen that if I want to keep the formatting of the range and don't want to copy the range as a picture then I need to use:

```
ppapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting")
```

But I cannot get this to work this is what I am trying to do:

```
    Sub CreatePP()
    Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ppTextBox As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim iLastRowReport As Integer
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim templatePath As String

Set ppapp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

Set pptPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Desktop\Template.pptx")
ppapp.Visible = True
Sheets("Tables").Select
Range("A27:D48").Copy

ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides (5)
ppapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting")
```

Comment: What does the code say if you record a macro, and do the copy/paste? (Or is that where the above comes from)?  Also "...the quality is not very good", how so? Is it being pasted as an image?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes it is being pasted as an image and when I just manually copy and paste the quality is better. The error is "compile error: method or data member not found"

Comment: What if you take off all the `Top`,`Left`, etc?

Comment: @BruceWayne nope still the same error.

Comment: You get an error? I used your top macro, and it works for me.  It copies the rows, but no errors.  Can you quickly perhaps explain what the data is/looks like, and what you want it to look like in PowerPoint?  Keep in mind you're copying 40 rows, so it may not be able to look very "pretty" in the end. If you do this manually, can you get it looking better/like you want?

Comment: @BruceWayne the top macro where I use .CopyPicture works fine. It is the simple .Copy that doesn't work for me. Does the .Copy work for you
? The other issue is that when I try to record the macro I can't get it just records to copy but not the pasting to PowerPoint.

Comment: Sorry - yeah, same here. `.Copy` gives error, `.CopyPicture` works, but isn't clear enough.  Also yeah, I tried too and the macro recorder doesn't record the PowerPoint part.  Are you able to manually get the range to paste, and look okay? Or is that also hard? (I'm just thinking the Excel range may be too large to make look 'pretty' in PowerPoint).

Comment: I also have no issue using .Copy. Also I found that a manual paste actually doesn't turn it into a picture. --- .emf instead!

Comment: @CodyG. what version of Excel and PowerPoint are you using? I am using excel 2010.

Comment: @BruceWayne the manually copy and pasting of the range looks fine, but the bigger issue is that it can't be automated.

Comment: @AdamWarner 2013 --- I also added the Microsoft Office 15.0 reference to my excel VBA code. --- All I can suggest is that you try a basic spreadsheet/testcase  and see if the code works. I used a test case of 8 cells, which is slightly different than yours A6 to Q46.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting it as a EnhancedMetafile?

```
Set myShapeRange = PPPres.Slides(18).PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
With myShapeRange
            .Top = 86.8969
            .Left = 19.98417
            .Height = 150.7964
            .Width = 600.5262
End With
```

Function parameters via https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745158.aspx

Comment: I get the same error; "compile error: method or data member not found"

Comment: I don't have any issues with your code, but I found that when you manually paste the file it uses an EnhancedMetaFile instead.